# Error installing Google cloud SDK on Windows 10

Tags: google-app-engine

Whenever I try installing the google cloud sdk, I get the following error:

```
Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud SDK (y/N)? n

ERROR: (gcloud.components.list) The provided path must exist.
Activate code page: 437
Google Cloud SDK installer will now exit.
```

I'm using the latest version (299.0.0) and python3. I've tried older versions too. I am not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Did you try to run the installer file as administrator?

Comment: @Jaroslav Yes, I ran it as administrator. I have tried various versions of both the sdk and python and I get the same error.

Comment: The possible solutions you can find here https://b.corp.google.com/issues/146458519.